# Why is my portfolio gallery not filtering right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a portfolio gallery and I'd like to add some buttons so user could filter out the gallery.
Button 'All' is working fine, but other 3 buttons are not.
I can't spot the problem in my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div id="portfolio-sort">
        <a href="#" id="all">ALL</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="a">A</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="b">B</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="c">C</a>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-content">
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var Portfolio = {
    sort: function (items) {
        Portfolio.hideAll($('#portfolio-content *'));
        Portfolio.showAll(items);
    },
    showAll: function (items) {
    items.fadeIn(700);
    },
    hideAll: function (items) {
        items.hide();
    },
    doSort: function () {
        $('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function () {
            var $a = $(this);
            if (!$a.is('#all')) {
                var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');
                Portfolio.sort(items);
            } else {
                var items = $('#portfolio-content *');
                Portfolio.hideAll(items);
                Portfolio.showAll(items);
            }
        });
    }
};

Portfolio.doSort();
```

Function is supposed to filter on button click, I'd like to have 3 different values and one 'all' value that would return all images.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey your code seems to be working correctly, which version of jQuery are you using? Worked for me with version 3.1.0. Maybe post a link to a jsbin/codepen and I can take a look.

Comment: The issue with your updated code is that on this line:

`Portfolio.hideAll($('#portfolio-content *'));`

It is selecting ALL elements and therefore hiding the image tags as well. Just change this to be more specific:

`Portfolio.hideAll($('#portfolio-content > div'));`

This will select the immediate children of #portfolio-content that are divs

Answer (score 0):

As has already been stated, your code works just fine. See snippet below working with version 2.2.4

```js
var Portfolio = {
    sort: function (items) {
        Portfolio.hideAll($('#portfolio-content *'));
        Portfolio.showAll(items);
    },
    showAll: function (items) {
    items.fadeIn(700);
    },
    hideAll: function (items) {
        items.hide();
    },
    doSort: function () {
        $('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function () {
            var $a = $(this);
            if (!$a.is('#all')) {
                var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');
                Portfolio.sort(items);
            } else {
                var items = $('#portfolio-content *');
                Portfolio.hideAll(items);
                Portfolio.showAll(items);
            }
        });
    }
};

Portfolio.doSort();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="portfolio">
    <div id="portfolio-sort">
        <a href="#" id="all">ALL</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="a">A</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="b">B</a>
        <a href="#" data-cat="c">C</a>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio-content">
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="a">A</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="c">C</div>
        <div class="portfolio-item" data-cat="b">B</div>
    </div>

</div>
```